# Psychological Experiment

Tags: riddle, wordplay, steganography

You're walking home one day and **BAM**! somebody hits you in the back of the head. When you wake up, you are strapped down to a chair, in a dimly lit room. Sitting infront of you is a guy with a weird goatee. He says the following to you:

"Well hello, there. Now, don't be afraid, I'm only a psychotic psychologist. Get it? Hah! Now, I apologize for the incident earlier regarding knocking you out. But there really was no other way to get you to agree? I mean what was I supposed to say, 'Hello, child, would you like to be part of a psychological experiment where you could die?' I didn't think so either. How did it feel to be knocked out? Do you fear the dark? I hope not. I know you can't see me right now, but I don't care. By the way, I really like drinking as well as rescuing koalas. Did you know I saved a whole family once? I think I've had too much wine! Just answer my questions. What is the answer anyways? Do you fear the dark? I think its light indeed. Hee hee hee hee hee. I'm crazy, I know. Now, there is no reason to be afraid. Maybe you shoudln't trust me. Here's what it is: I ask you a question, and you tell me the most obvious answer. The one that fills your brain, screaming at you telling you its the right answer. You don't have to panic, all you have to do is agree. Now your a pretty bad child, that's why I picked you. No one would *ever* want you after all. Any how, here's the little riddle you have to solve. Solve it, and I'll free you, don't solve it, and I'll kill you.

I'm the fastest thing in the universe.

Nothing can ever catch me.

I engulf the shadows,

I can get pretty hot, too.

I break at dawn,

Make you blind.

I am a void,

I am empty.

Fill me up and destroy me.

I am nothing.

I blind your sight.

I am _____

What am I?"

How do you survive from this maniac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> Void/Darkness?

I'm the fastest thing in the universe.

> Darkness is the absence of light, so it's as fast as how fast light can leave something - lightspeed.

Nothing can ever catch me.

> Darkness is intangible.

I engulf the shadows

> Shadows only exist if there's light, not if there's complete darkness. Complete darkness will consume shadows.

I can get pretty hot, too.

> Black objects absorb all light and thus heat up faster.

I break at dawn

> Dawn introduces sunlight, 'breaking' darkness.

Make you blind. I blind your sight.

> You're blind if you can only see the dark.

I am a void, I am empty. I am nothing.

> Self explanatory. It's the absence of everything, even light.

Fill me up and destroy me.

> Darkness is destroyed if you fill it with anything that may emit light, or light itself.

I am _____ What am I?"

> **Darkness**

Comment: Nice! +1. You answered the riddle. However, it is also tagged steganography for a reason. Perhaps you should look at the block of text.

Comment: @North: I think it's likely that the answer is hidden in the second but last paragraph. You probably meant to render this as verse. (Looking at the post's source in edit mode suggests so.) If that's the case, please edit the question. You can introduce hard line breaks with two or more spaces at the end of a line or with the `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two questions going on here.

The missing word to "I am ____", answered by @Votbear.

And a second question "What am I?"

> Most of the riddle can be construed as hyperbole, including the phrase I am darkness. The ravings of a maniac that considers themselves uncatchable, a hot head, a night owl, using darkness as cover for attack and darkness to blind captives. An individual with an aching void to fill, a need to be fulfilled, satiated, who is otherwise nothing.

The answer that is "the most obvious answer. The one that fills your brain, screaming at you telling you its the right answer."

What am I?

> An evil maniac pedophile murderer, a suitable foe for a dark superhero like Batman.

Comment: Nice answer! You and Votbear are both correct. However, look even deeper and you'll find more hidden messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

> Light

I'm the fastest thing in the universe.

> nothing is faster than light that we know of

Nothing can ever catch me.

> we cannot grab light or travel at its speed

I engulf the shadows,

> it makes shadows disappear

I can get pretty hot, too.

> infrared light is hot

I break at dawn,

> the sun produces light

Make you blind.

> bright lights impair vision

I am a void,

> light is intangible

I am empty.

> it doesn't seem have volume? (it does have mass and volume)

Comment: Incorrect. this riddle was designed to soud like light the answer was light (hence, psychological experiment). However, if you can give me more explanation of why it could be light (there's one in particuar I'm thiking about) I'll +1.

Comment: @North the "Fill me up and destroy me." line confuses me because you can fill up a dark room with stuff and it will remain dark, but if you fill up a lighted room it can be come dark